# Show me how this equation is true $\dfrac {a}{b}=\dfrac {b}{~\frac{a}{2}~}=\dfrac {2b}{a}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a$ is the long side of an A4 paper and $b$ is the shorter side.

$$\frac {a}{b}=\frac {b}{~\frac{a}{2}~}=\frac {2b}{a}$$

I can't seem to wrap my head around how $\dfrac {a}{b}= \dfrac {b}{~\frac{a}{2}~}$ is true.

Comment: There is something wrong with the second equality...

Comment: The formula is not correct

Comment: it's based on this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#A_series

Comment: in the second term $2a$ should be in fact $a/2$

Comment: yeah, I corrected my mistake.

Comment: "*I can't seem to wrap my head around how... is true*"  It seems like you might be under the impression that they are claiming that this equality is true for all values of $a$ and $b$.  That is not what is being claimed.  It is a special case and result of the exact values of $a$ and $b$ that were chosen for the side lengths of A4 paper.  Had the dimensions been different, then this would not have been the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: A4 Paper Dimension Derivation]

It's not something that holds generally, it's from the property of A4 paper that its aspect ratio is the same when folded in half (that is, the ratio of the long side to the sort side is the same when folded in half):

$$\frac{\text{Long side}}{\text{Short side}}=\frac{\color{green}{\bullet}}{\color{orange}{\bullet}}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a/2}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is approximately true because of the dimensions selected for paper.  It is not true in general.  $A4$ paper is $210$ mm $\times 297$ mm.  We can then compute
$$\frac {210}{297}\approx 0.70707\\
\frac {297}{2\cdot 210}\approx 0.70714\\
\frac 12\sqrt 2 \approx 0.70711$$
The exact solution to $\frac ab=\frac b{2a}$ is $b=a\sqrt 2$  We can see the actual ratios are very close to this.  The advantage is that the aspect ratio of a sheet that is $210 \times 297$ is very close to the aspect ratio of a sheet $297 \times 420$.  US standard paper does the same thing with our version of $A4$ being $8\frac 12 \times 11$ inches and the next larger size being $11 \times 17$ inches.

Answer (score 1):

With the corrected expression, the formula says that the ratio between the long side and the short side is the same as the ratio between the short side and half of the long side. This is just the definition of the A paper format. What it means is that $$\frac ab=\frac b{a/2}=\frac{2b}a$$
Which has the solution $$a^2=2b^2$$ or $a=\sqrt2 b$ (we only have positive distances).
Plugging it into the equation above
$$\frac{\sqrt 2 b}b=\sqrt 2$$
and $$\frac b{b\sqrt 2 /2}=\sqrt 2$$
So the equation is valid